# "TypeError: copy() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dst' when importing external libraries in IDLE"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm facing an issue in my Python development environment, specifically when working in IDLE. Whenever I try to import external libraries using statements like import library_name, I encounter the following error message:

```
TypeError: copy() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dst'
```

However, the same code runs without any issues when I compile it to an executable using tools like PyInstaller. This error seems to be unique to IDLE.

I have checked the following:

1.My Python environment is up-to-date.
2.The libraries are correctly installed using pip.
3.I'm not using any custom variables or identifiers conflicting with library names.
4.I'm using the same Python version in both IDLE and when compiling to an executable.

I'm looking for insights on what could be causing this error specifically in the IDLE environment and how I can resolve it. Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a traceback for this error message as well?

Comment: It would be even better if you can show a code snippet that is associated with the error.

Comment: For example ```import pygame``` or ```from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip```